# SWT FocusListener focusLost() is never called

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have a Composite that contains a table with columns. The columns have certain validation, and if the field values don't pass the validation, they are coloured red and set an error message.
I want to have a Listener that checks if there is any error message set by the columns. I added a listener to the composite but it is never called.
I thought that the focusLost() method should be called whenever I click away from the composite into other composites or elsewhere within the shell. But it is never called.

```
myComposite = new MyComposite(myGroup, myEditor, getModel(), SWT.NONE,
            calculator, this, application, modelService, partService, progressService, shell);
    myComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().span(21, 1).grab(true, true).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP).applyTo(myComposite);
    
    FocusListener focusListener = new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
        {
            if (myComposite.getErrorMessage() != null) {
            getValidator().getDecorator().setError(myComposite, myComposite.getErrorMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) { /** nothing */  }
    };
    
myComposite.addFocusListener(focusListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is much old, I'll try to suggest what may have gone wrong.

I don't have enough code in the question to determine the reason exactly, but common case is that children elements of Composite have focus, not the parent one. That's why this outer Composite may not generate focus events - it doesn't operate in the events cycle at all. So, I can suggest use focus loosing checkings on the internal elements, like this for example:

```
entireElement.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, event -> {
    // put element validation mechanics here
});
```